# limit for pasting from excel sheet to sharepoint list in quick edit mode

Tags: 2013, list, excel

Is there a limit for pasting data from Excel sheet to sharepoint list in quick edit mode?

I want to paste (and replace) around 10-13K records from excel to sharepoint list

Is it supported for such high volumes in SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

Limit is 100 items. Same as drag&drop in document library. You could try link SharePoint list with Access and then update data in Access linked table.

In this case you could have new problems if you have "user" field.

Comment: was it supported in SharePoint 2010 to paste more than 10K items? I am able to paste more than 10K items from excel to list in edit mode

Comment: The logic behind quick edit mode is changed in sp2013.. so it could work without activex controls